# Access Combo Box based on Form Record Source

Tags: ms-access

I have a combo box that I want to display options based on the record source of the form. However, the record source is dynamic rather than static (i.e. it changes while doing certain things). How can I make it so that the combo box requeries itself based of what the record source is at any point in the process.

Comment: In whatever routines change the recordsource of the form, you have to alter the combo box's rowsource. There's no other way around it. How are you changing the records displayed in the form? Tell us that and then we can suggest how to handle synchronizing the combo box with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the requery methode:

```
combobox.Requery
```

Comment: but that will only requery the combobox based on what its original rowsource is. I need to attach the row source to the record source which is dynamic and changes.

Comment: You can always change the rowsource of a combobox by using its RowSource property. Then you requery the combobox immediately, i think it works

Comment: If you're setting the Rowsource, a requery is redundant.